# What is time constant for this UC3845 circuit?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, pwm

[image]

Time constant tau=R*C=100 (us) Am I right??

How to get relation equation about V_ref and V_c?

me:

[image]

Am I right?

Comment: What's the intention? You know that those R and C determines the switching frequency, don't you?

Comment: I want to know time constant